# Qt Display tooltip after mouse hover on QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: c++, qt, qevent

I'm using QGraphicView to show game map that consist QGraphicsPixmapItems. I need to show tooltip on mouse hover at QGraphicsPixmapItem.

For saving QGraphicsPixmapItem position I using MazeItem:

```
#ifndef MAZEITEM_H
#define MAZEITEM_H

#include <QPoint>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

class MazeItem
{
private:
    QPoint myPosition;
    QString myToolTip;

public:
    MazeItem();
    QPoint position() const;
    QString toolTip() const;
    void setToolTip(const QString &toolTip);
    void setPosition(const QPoint &position);
    QPoint getPosition();
    QGraphicsPixmapItem * pixmap;
};

#endif // MAZEITEM_H
```

I have widget class to display game map:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QToolTip>
#include "mazeitem.h"

class MazeGUI : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QGraphicsView * graphicsView;
    QGraphicsScene * graphicsScene;
    QString sceneString;
    int imageSize;
    QList<MazeItem> mazeItems;
    void addItem(int x, int y, QPixmap picture);
    bool event(QEvent *event);
    int itemAt(const QPoint &pos);

public:
    explicit MazeGUI(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setScene(QString sceneString);

signals:

public slots:
    void redraw();

};
#endif // MAZEGUI_H
```

In constructor I set mouse tracking.

```
MazeGUI::MazeGUI(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
    ...
}
```

This is how I add new maze item.

```
void MazeGUI::addItem(int x, int y, QPixmap picture)
{
    MazeItem mazeItem;
    mazeItem.setPosition(QPoint(x, y));
    mazeItem.setToolTip("text");
    mazeItem.pixmap = this->graphicsScene->addPixmap(picture);
    mazeItem.pixmap->setPos(y, x);
    mazeItems.append(mazeItem);
}
```

And this I have from Qt tutorials,

```
bool MazeGUI::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip) {

        // HERE - it never goes here!!      

        QHelpEvent *helpEvent = static_cast<QHelpEvent *>(event);
        int index = itemAt(helpEvent->pos());
        if (index != -1) {
            QToolTip::showText(helpEvent->globalPos(), mazeItems[index].toolTip());
        } else {
            QToolTip::hideText();
            event->ignore();
        }

        return true;
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}

int MazeGUI::itemAt(const QPoint &pos)
{
    for (int i=0; i < mazeItems.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (mazeItems[i].getPosition() == pos)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the tooltip is not showing up, the even can't even start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was adding the tooltip on wrong object:

Instead of:

```
mazeItem.setToolTip("text");
```

It should be:

```
mazeItem.pixmap->setToolTip("text");
```